# Extending of resulted xml node attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Question for those who is familiar with xslt. Shortly - i have a need to a extend an attribute some times by one transformation. Does anyone know how to do it? For example, i have the xml

```
<article type="funny">
   <firstclass>big</firstclass>
   <secondclass>smooth</secondclass>
   hot-dog
</article>
```

and i need to have output:

```
<div class="funny big smooth">hot-dog</div>
```

Can it be done with separate template for each tag or attribute(firstclass, secondclass and type)?

Of course i can type something like this:

```
<xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>&#160;
   <xsl:value-of select="secondclass"/>&#160;
   <xsl:value-of select="firstclass"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

but there is a lot of attributes that could be placed or not and can expand class or not, so it will be perfect to may something like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
```

for handle all of them withou hardcoding.

Thanks!

Comment: and of course i can fo it by applying two xslt - one to make fake class tags one-by class and another to cathce them all. But it should be done in one xslt=(

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="article">
     <div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@type | *"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
     </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="article/*">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="article/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<article type="funny">
    <firstclass>big</firstclass>
    <secondclass>smooth</secondclass>
    hot-dog 
</article>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div class="funny big smooth">hot-dog</div>
```

Comment: So the elements (@type | *) will only extend the class attr and text() will extend body of result. But what i want is to omit hardcode this, becouse i don't know wich nodes will expand the resulted div class and which will expand body.

Comment: @DaniilGrudzinskiy: Could you, please, re-phrase this? I don't understand what you are talking about...